# Does the poison damage from a Naga Monk's bite scale?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, mtg-plane-shift

I'm building a naga monk (using the statistics from [Plane Shift: Amonkhet](https://media.wizards.com/2017/downloads/magic/plane-shift_amonkhet.pdf)), and the bite attack states that:

> Natural Weapons. Your fanged maw and constricting serpentine body are natural weapons, which you can use to make unarmed strikes. If you hit with your
> bite, you deal piercing damage equal to 1d4 + your Strength modifier, and your target must make a Constitution saving throw (DC 8 + your proficiency bonus + your Constitution modifier). On a failed save, the target takes 1d4 poison damage. [...]

It makes sense for the piercing damage to scale, and for the bite to become Dex-based. However, I can't find anything that says whether Martial Arts allows the 1d4 poison damage to scale.